# Java/Hibernate Application accessing Teradata

Tags: hibernate, teradata

We are considering setting up our Java/Hibernate based web application to access tables in Teradata.  This is for a regular web application and not specifically a reporting system, although there are real time reports users can request through the tool.

The reason we are considering this move is because data we'd like to access is already being managed in this Teradata database and we're trying to avoid having to copy it over into a separate database and have 2 copies of it.

It seems to work fine in the sense that we were able to use the JDBC driver and the Hibernate Teradata dialect and access the tables.

But we are wondering if other people have had experience with this sort of setup hitting Teradata?  If so, did it work out?  Were there problems you can warn us about.  Does it seem like an OK idea in general?

One thing we noticed right away was the dialect itself seems kind of incomplete so we're feeling like maybe Hibernate with Teradata isn't really that common of a setup.

Please let us know your thoughts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Hibernate specifically.  I do have some web apps that access Teradata.  If you only need read access, I recommend creating views for your application.  Specifically, put LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS in your view definition.  If your app starts locking tables when it doesn't need to you could experience deadlocks with other processes.

After you have everything set up, actively monitor things in Teradata Viewpoint for a while as your app is running to see if there are performance issues or things that should be optimized.